# How to access Groovy file from Jenkins Seed Job using DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Create Jenkins Seed Job using DSL Plugin - Where i can pass Git Repo location to create the Jenkins jobs for the repo. The Job is created programmatically in the repo. Seed Job should read the groovy file in the repo and create the new job.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- Checkout `Groovy` file from Seed Job
- Access file  programmatically from code of Seed Job (some SCM tools provide API, ie. Bitbucket, github)